# Matrix representation of a set of vectors in a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

If $ a \in \mathbb{R}$ and we define

$\tau_ap(x) =\frac{1}{x-a} \int_{a}^{x} p(y) dy$ in which $ \tau_a: \mathcal{P}_2\to \mathcal{P}_2$.

I need to compute the matrix representation of $\tau_a$ with respect to the basis $v_1 = 1, v_2 = x,$ and $ v_3=x^2$.

Thus far, I have computed to the following (in the most simplified format):

$v_1 = 1$: $ \frac{1}{x-a} \int_{a}^{x} 1 dx = (x-a) (\frac{1}{x-a}) = 1$.

$v_2 = x$: $ \frac{1}{x-a} \int_{a}^{x} x dx = \frac{1}{x-a} (\frac{1}{2}x^2 - \frac{1}{2}a^2) = \frac{1}{2}(x + a)$.

$v_3 = x^2$: $ \frac{1}{x-a} \int_{a}^{x} x^2 dx = \frac{1}{x-a} (\frac{1}{2}x^3 - \frac{1}{2}a^3) = \frac{1}{3} (x^2 - ax +a^2)$

For the purpose of writing the representation matrix, I will go ahead and distribute the results as such:

$v_1 = 1, $

$v_2 = \frac{1}{2}x +\frac{1}{2}a, $

$v_3 = \frac{1}{3}x^2 + \frac{1}{3}ax +\frac{1}{3}a^2$

I am having a bit of trouble writing the matrix representation of this. This is what I have obtained so far but I'm not sure it's correct:

$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \frac{1}{2}a & \frac{1}{3}a^2 \\
    0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3}a  \\
\
    0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix}
$

Did I approach this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small mistake. The first time you wrote $v_3$, you wrote that it's equal to $\frac13(x^2-ax+a^2)$, but after that the $-$ sign vanishes (twice).